# Behaviour of function defined by Taylor series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am trying to understand if the knowledge of the Taylor coefficients of a function can be used to understand the behaviour of the function.

For example, let $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the analytic function defined by
$$
f (x) = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{2^{k^3}}
$$
How can one visualize this function, for example its behaviour at infinity? Can one give a formula in terms of (integrals of) elementary functions? (For some reason, [I can't get WolframAlpha to plot this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sum+from+k%3D1+to+infinity+x%5Ek%2F%282%5E%28k%5E3%29%29).)

Is there a function roughly of this form (whose Taylor coefficients are bounded by $C^{-k^2}$ for some constant $C > 0$) which tends to $0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$?

Comment: Note that if all the Taylor coefficients are positive, the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \infty$ because the sum is bigger than the first term (and the first term is a linear function with a constant coefficient.  If you're going to get zero in the limit, the coefficients must lead to (significant) cancellation.

Comment: And coefficients bounded by $C^{-k^2}$ aren't large enough to get that cancellation.  Consider $\sum_k C^{-k^2}$ in the base $C$.  This is a very sparse sequence of $1$s separated by rapidly widening runs of $0$s.  For any $x$, there is a $K$ sufficiently large such that for all $k > K$, $(\pm x)^k C^{-k^2}$ isn't large enough to bridge its runs of $0$s (and this failure is only more egregious as $k$ increases).  So you can't get the cancellation you want with such rapidly decreasing coefficients.

Comment: @Eric you are right - I see now that the Op wants very fast decreasing coefficients

Comment: @Conrad : It happens.  To me too.  More often that I choose to admit.

Comment: @EricTowers So are you saying that the "cancellation" is not possible even with introducing signs?

Comment: Introducing signs will produce cancellation.  The awesomely rapidly decreasing coefficients prevents enough cancellation.

Comment: @EricTowers I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is no (assuming $C>1$ as for $C \le 1$ the answer is trivially yes as $e^{-x^2}$ shows) as any entire (nonconstant) function of order less than $1/2$ cannot be bounded on any half line (it follows from Lindelof applied to $f(z^2)$)

Since for $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ the order is given by $\limsup \frac{n \log n}{-\log |a_n|}$ this means that we cannot have $\frac{n \log n}{-\log |a_n|} <1/2-\epsilon$ for $n$ large enough or equivalently we cannot have $|a_n| << e^{-(2+\epsilon)n\log n}$ for any $\epsilon>0$ (and of course $e$ can be replaced by any $C>1$)

The result is sharp as $\cos \sqrt z=\sum \frac{(-1)^nz^n}{(2n)!}$ shows

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm missing enough background to fill in the details. I'm assuming you're referring to [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f's_theorem). Also, do you have a reference for the order of a function? I'm seeing this for the first time and I'm not sure how to use this to arrive at the conclusion.

Comment: The theorem one uses is actually Phragmen-Lindelof (though usually it is shortened to the generic Lindelof maximum principle which comes from the theory of harmonic functions) and gives conditions for a function that is bounded on the boundary of a sector of some angle $\alpha \le \pi$  to be bounded on the sector itself; when the angle is $\pi$ (so the sector is a half plane) the condition is $|f(z)| \le K_ae^{C_a|z|^a}$ for some $a<1$ and that follows from order being strictly less than $a$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle#Special_cases

Comment: for order of an entire function (and its formula in terms of the Taylor coefficients) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type